# How to forward GoDaddy email to Gmail with Non GoDaddy DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail, godaddy

I have a domain (example.com) through GoDaddy and a VPS at a hosting company.

On GoDaddy's site, I've set the domain servers for example.com to that of the hosting company (everything working fine).

From this setup, I'd like to get email forwarded from name@example.com to go to my gmail account.

I found this article, but think that is dependent on using GoDaddy's email servers.

[Using Gmail for GoDaddy Email](http://joshbetz.com/2008/12/using-gmail-for-godaddy-email/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use GoDaddy's e-mail, you should just follow [Google's instructions](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33352) for how to set your [GoDaddy supplied](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33353) domain's MX records to point at Google's servers.

Comment: Thanks for the resonse Alnitak. But, I think those instructions are for "Google Apps for Domains", not just a random Gmail account.

Comment: If you don't want to get a Google Apps account, you will need to redirect your email at the application level, meaning that you will need to configure your email servers, not at the DNS level. The only way that DNS level changes will work is with something like a Google Apps account.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a free gmail account.  I retrieve all of my mail from GoDaddy using POP3.  However, buyer beware.  I discovered that some of my mail had not been properly retrieved and was over 3 days old (I had to manually run the service to pull the mail), including a job offer. :(

For those that are curious, it can be setup in gmail under settings -> Account and Import.

Comment: The more e-mail you get, the more frequently Gmail checks for new e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got another article about setting up google apps. I’ve since gone this route and just use the Google Apps account to forward my mail to my gmail account. This makes it much easier to manage. http://joshbetz.com/2010/01/google-apps/